Comparing amount of investment under two situations
I am studying the following problem -
Investor has $1 and he has to split it between two assets. These are risk-free assets.
Under scenario 1 - These are normal times so he don't have to worry about anything, just the net returns.
Interest from asset 1 is A and interest from asset 2 is B
Total returns for the investor is
$$ \sqrt(x) A + \sqrt(1-x) B $$
So, he will choose x (amount of investment in asset 1) -
$$ \frac{\sqrt(x)}{\sqrt(1-x)} = \frac{A}{B} $$
Scenario 2: These are the hard times. His investment decision has an effect on other domains of his life, denoted by y
His total returns is given by -
$$ \sqrt(x) (C - y^2 + xy) + \sqrt(1-x) (D - y^2 - 3y + xy) $$
So, foc will be given by -
$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt(x)} (C - y^2 + xy) - \frac{1}{2\sqrt(1-x)} (D - y^2 - 3y + xy) + \sqrt(x) ( - 2y \frac{dy}{dx} + y + x\frac{dy}{dx}) + \sqrt(1-x) (- 3\frac{dy}{dx} - 2y \frac{dy}{dx} + x\frac{dy}{dx} + y) =0 $$
I have to compare x under scenario 1 and scenario 2
I know that
$$\frac{A}{B} < \frac{(C - y^2 + xy)}{(D - y^2 - 3y + xy)}$$
and
$$ 0>( - 2y \frac{dy}{dx} + y + x\frac{dy}{dx}) > (- 3\frac{dy}{dx} - 2y \frac{dy}{dx} + x\frac{dy}{dx} + y) $$
How can I prove that x under scenario 2 > x under scenario 1?
Please guide me with follow up action

So the proportions invested in either asset ($x$ and $1-x$) are put under the square root but the returns (e.g. $A$ and $B$) are not? What's $\sqrt k$ in the returns in scenario 2? Was it supposed to be $\sqrt x$?

@HerrK. Thanks for pointing it out, yes it's x (it was a typo). Reason I have taken sqrt of x because had it been x, he would have chosen x=1 for A>B. He wouldn't have been concerned about relative. And sqrt of x can be interpreted as investment left after paying some fees and you yet interest A on only that. Sorry, I should have mentioned it in my question.
